# Is there any way to achieve a Flutter top snackbar?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want to create a simple snackbar that come from top of the screen instesd of bottom.In flutter i have used native snackbar but it does not have such feature.

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Comment: I need something similar to snackbar,  toast is ok but only in case If I did not find any solution.

Comment: My bad, I misread the question. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Here you go, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flushbar

```
RaisedButton(
  child: Text('Show Top Snackbar'),
  onPressed: () {
    Flushbar(
      flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.TOP,
    )
      ..title = "Hey Ninja"
      ..message = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry"
      ..duration = Duration(seconds: 3)
      ..show(context);
  },
),
```

Comment: Yes, I have used this plugin as well but it has a major bug if you show two snackbar in a row than the old one does not dismiss on its own. That's why I was looking for some alternative.
Thanks for your help but I am looking for something more.If you have some more suggestions than please suggest.

Comment: Well, you can try to prevent user to create 2 snackbars at the same time.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a bug to me. I believe snackbar behaves the same way. Imagine having 5 messages to show at once and since the previous ones get dismissed automatically to show the next, only the last snackbar is going to appear.

Comment: No, actually what happens with this plugin is that if we are showing a message on button click and you press the button 8 times very fast that you get 8 snackbar one after other, then only the most recent will dismiss on its ownand  other will stay there until you swipe them out which means you need to swipe 7 snackbars which is not user friendly.

Comment: `flushbar` is now labeled as "Discontinued" on pub.dev 

Comment: I found another_flushbar: ^1.10.24, but my question is. Is it safe to use because flushbar Discontinued on pub.dev and reason i dont know

Comment: I use `another_flushbar` alright instead.

Comment: You can prevent the multiple button clicks by having a validation or count ( idk the purpose of the button so..).

Comment: The pub does not allow installation as it does not support null safety.

Answer (score 24):

You can set a margin using the device's height to achieve this:

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
    content: Text('Snackbar message'),
    behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
    ),
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100,
        right: 20,
        left: 20),
  ));
```

Comment: Worked for me thanks @David Jentjens

Comment: The issue with this solution is that it's blocking. The screen becomes unresponsive (doesn't receive touches) until the snack bar is dismissed

Comment: @johnnyMac You are right, but as it stands at the moment I don't think there is a workaround to this issue.

Comment: @johnnyMac you can solve this issue by setting dismissDirection to DismissDirection.none

Answer (score 11):

Use this package https://pub.dev/packages/another_flushbar

```
Flushbar(
  message: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry",
  icon: Icon(
    Icons.info_outline,
    size: 28.0,
    color: Colors.blue[300],
    ),
  duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
  leftBarIndicatorColor: Colors.blue[300],
)..show(context);
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty good alternative. It has 130/130 pub points on pub.dev.

Comment: You are right, i have used it but could not keep because functionality was little different one.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example based on [the answer from fatih](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65372382)

[image]

```
void showTopSnackBar(
  String message, {
  bool isSuccess = true,
  Color? color,
  Duration? duration,
}) {
  final backgroundColor =
      color ?? (isSuccess ? Colors.green[600] : Colors.red[600]);

  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      duration: duration ?? const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      content: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          width: double.maxFinite,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: backgroundColor,
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(15),
            ),
          ),
          child: Text(
            message,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your widget with `Column` and set `mainAxisAlignment` to `MainAxisAlignment.start`. Additionally, set SnackBar's color transparent.

```
Column(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [yourWidget()], ),
```

Comment: I apply this ---> SnackBar(
      content: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container( bla bla bla ),],),)

Comment: @pedrozopayares could you give a full example on how you apply it because im trying to understand and apply your solution

Comment: @LearnFlutter of course. I'm not sure if it's the best, but I did it this way https://gist.github.com/pedrozopayares/f26d159f9295ee6b299ca42f8a383658

Comment: It makes your Snackbar to go full-screen. Why would you propose such a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use Flutter Package [another_flushbar](https://pub.dev/packages/another_flushbar/install). It will give you the flexibility you need without any overlay of your entire screen.

Material SnackBar is currently meant for bottom only. As of this date, there is no reasonable way to have it be top down without creating a total screen height sized widget.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fixed banner which does not dismiss after some time rather on user action then you can use `MaterialBanner` and show it using `showMaterialBanner`

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('MaterialBanner')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Show'),
          onPressed: () => _showBanner(context),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showBanner(BuildContext context) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showMaterialBanner(
      MaterialBanner(
        content: const Text('I am a Banner'),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('Close'),
            onPressed: () => ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentMaterialBanner(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```