# Flutter showsnackbar at top of the screen?

Tags: flutter, snackbar

how to show flutter snackbar at top of the screen ?

```
 ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar(context,Strings.order_not_selected));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194999/is-there-any-way-to-achieve-a-flutter-top-snackbar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to achieve a Flutter top snackbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194999/is-there-any-way-to-achieve-a-flutter-top-snackbar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Getx library for it, you can customize it accordingly.

```
 Get.snackbar(
              "Title of Snackbar",
               "Message of SnackBar",
               icon: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white),
               snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
                 );
```

Comment: this is not working

Comment: it will work, make MaterialTheme in the main as GetMaterialApp,

Comment: it works, but how to show only title